# HTTP request outside of redux actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on react app + redux.
I have some HTTP requests that I don't think that should be in the state of my app. (for example : in case of autocomplete, I fetch only relevant data, I don't have to use this data anywhere but in the specific input).
Is it a bad practice to have folder of "statless services" inside an react-redux app? 
Do I have to keep every request result in the state? 
What about POST and PUT requests? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking broadly is not bad to keep something out of the state if it's not relevant or shouldn't influence render or state.
Take for example a live graph that updates every second. You don't want it to trigger a re render every time it updates.

Or some external service for example Google Maps Auto Complete.  It takes control of the dom, does external calls and so on but at the end of the day what you want for your app is the location when the user perform some action.
All the several state changes that it does on the map and on the info until the user decide that there is his location is not relevant and shouldn't be a part of your state.

Answer (score 0):

This could be opinion based... It's a bad practice, that's transient state no one else is interested in.

I suggest you to use https://redux-saga.js.org/ to avoid pollute your logic with side effects and take care of this common transient states.